# Creating compass for app but compass not working if Orientation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I am building a compass into an IOS app that I'm developing. Currently I am building on iPad but am facing a huge issue when switching orientations whilst on the view

IF I open the view while the app is already in landscape/portrait mode, the compass appears perfectly fine (like 1st image) however IF i go in Portrait mode for example and then turn to landscape, the whole UI of the compass goes crazy (see second image)

My code in ViewDidLoad looks something like this:

```
//start updating compass
locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.headingFilter = 1;
locationManager.delegate=self;
[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

//get coords of current location
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D fromLoc = [location coordinate];

//mecca:
CLLocationCoordinate2D toLoc = [location coordinate];
toLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.4167, 39.8167);


//calculate the bearing between current location and Mecca

float fLat = degreesToRadians(fromLoc.latitude);
float fLng = degreesToRadians(fromLoc.longitude);
float tLat = degreesToRadians(toLoc.latitude);
float tLng = degreesToRadians(toLoc.longitude);

float degree = radiandsToDegrees(atan2(sin(tLng-fLng)*cos(tLat), cos(fLat)*sin(tLat)-sin(fLat)*cos(tLat)*cos(tLng-fLng)));

if (degree >= 0) {
    bearing  = degree;
} else {
    bearing = degree+360;
}
NSLog(@"bearing: %f", bearing);

//rotate the needle from true north
float MnewRad =  degreesToRadians(bearing);
needleImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(MnewRad);//rotate the number of degrees from north

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {

//compass
float oldRad =  -manager.heading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
float newRad =  -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;

CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
theAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRad];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRad];
theAnimation.duration = 0.3f;
[compassView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateMyRotation"];
compassView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);

}
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this because its driving me crazy! Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am making a Qibla functionality for another app, and have compass issues, but I have to say your issue is completely unrelated to the compass functionality.

You said, when you rotate the device, the views get messed up. That seems like an obvious view layout problem. Depending on whether you are using auto layout or not, I would at least suggest that you add all the compass views into a single view container, first. That view should have a fixed size and centered in the view. (aka `UIAutoResizingMaskFlexibleTopMargin`, `BottomMargin`, `RightMargin`, `LeftMargin`).

Then, I am not sure if the rotation is working well for you, but I use `transform.rotation.z`, because the rotation happens on the z axis.

Finally, I suggest you would make the animation duration equal to the location update period, i.e duration = 0.1 or something

btw, I switched from using `CoreLocation` and moved to `CoreMotion`. It has a simpler compass API, and is much less resource demanding.

---

If you need to see code, here is my old code that uses CoreLocation:

```
- (int)fixOrientation {
    switch ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            return 0;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            return 90;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            return 270;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            return 180;
    }
}

CLHeading* newHeading = [MCLocationTracker sharedTracker].currentHeading;

[self dismissAlert];

float headingFloat = - newHeading.magneticHeading;
orientationCorrection = [self fixOrientation];
double angle = [[MCLocationTracker sharedTracker] qiblaBearing];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.05f
                      delay:0.f
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState)
                 animations:^{
                     self.compassImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(toRadian((headingFloat + orientationCorrection)));
                     if (fabs(kMCLocTrackerUndefinedAngle - angle) > 0.1f) {
                         self.arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(toRadian((headingFloat+angle) + orientationCorrection));
                     }
                 } 
                 completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

`didUpdateHeading` is called multiple times per second, so you don't need any animation here. I suspect you aren't seeing anything dues to the `0.3f` second animation lag. Set your angle rotation to the new value directly and it will still look smooth.

Comment: I appreciate your help. So what should I edit/remove specifically from my code?

Comment: Remove the CABasicAnimation and set the adjusted rotation transform yourself directly on the compassView.layer